# How to use Swift opaque types in combination with literals?

Tags: swift, generics, opaque-types

I have the following function

```swift
func greater<T: Comparable>(_ lhs: T, rhs: T) -> some Comparable {
    lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs
}
```

But when I try the following I get an error

```swift
greater(greater(1, 2), 3) // Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'some Comparable'
```

I understand the error but why is not the compiler able to infer that both types are actually `Int`s?

Comment: Why are you trying to use an opaque return type here? Why not return `T` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use an opaque return type for your needs. A simple generic return type should suffice.

The problem with an opaque return type in your example is that it masks the actual type information and hence the type of `greater(1, 2)` will not be the same as the type of `3` - `some Comparable` and `Int` are not the same, even if that `some Comparable` is actually an `Int`.

Moreover, you want to return the exact same type as your input arguments, which is `T`, not `some Comparable`. If your return type was `some Comparable`, you could easily return any other `Comparable` types from your function instead of returning the input type.

The correct implementation is:

```
func greater<T: Comparable>(_ lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T {
    lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When could that function possibly return another type than what was the input type so redeclare it as

```
func greater<T: Comparable>(_ lhs: T,_ rhs: T) -> T {
    lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs
}
```

or another way to look at it, when returning `some Comparable` we could change the function to below and it would still be valid

```
func greater<T: Comparable>(_ lhs: T,_ rhs: T) -> some Comparable {
    lhs > rhs ? "First argument" : "Second Argument"
}
```